# Magento - Custom Module Url

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, module

I have had a request to change the url of a module.

For example let's say the url is www.example.com/world

I need the url to be www.example.com/hello/world

I know that within the modules config xml you can change the  node to whatever you like (provided it's unique) but does not allow prepend /hello/

```
 <frontend>
    <routers>
        <anexample>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>An_Example</module>
                <frontName>hello/world</frontName>
            </args>
        </anexample>
    </routers>
 </frontend>
```

Does anyone have any idea how this can be done ? Some example code or even a point in the right direction would be appreciated!

Sorry if this isn't detailed enough, i'll be happy to post more of my code if required.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was pretty simple in the end. Instead of going to the hassle of creating a rewrite for it i just changed my frontname to 'hello' then created a controller called 'worldController'

Then in my indexController i just put a redirect to */world

Answer (score 3):

You can add rewrites into Magento's URL Rewrite Manager. Haven't tested following code. But hope it helps.

```
Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
->setIsSystem(0)
->setStoreId($storeId)   
->setOptions('RP')  
->setIdPath('index.php?cat=c' . $categoryId . '_' . $this->strip($data['name']) . '.html')
->setTargetPath($categoryModel->getUrlPath() . '.html')// Put the actual path
->setRequestPath('index.php?cat=c' . $categoryId . '_' . $this->strip($data['name']) . '.html') // put the path you want to display
->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following article by Allan Storm about the Magento rewrite

http://alanstorm.com/magento_dispatch_rewrites_intro

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a lot of help to me. 

I have already tried using <from> and <to> in xml to little affect. Often resulting in a 404 or not redirecting at all. I'm sure i'm just missing something obvious but i have been staring at it for so long it's all turned to gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

here i can give you idea to reach your solution it will sure help you

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <global>
   <rewrite>
      <some_unique_name_to_identify_this_rewrite>
        <from><![CDATA[#^/from_this/#]]></from>
        <to>/to_this/</to>
      </some_unique_name_to_identify_this_rewrite>
   </rewrite>
</global>
</config>
```

And if you want to do url rewrite with Admin functionality you can go throw [this link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/urlrewrite/index)

Also what you want to achieve could be done with Custom Url Rewrite. For example:

```
request path: hello/world

target path: 'world'
```

In this way you're making a destination of system rewrite yours start point.

hope this will sure help you

Answer (score 0):

**Access custom Module controller path as custom HTML Url Link**

Say http://domain.com/index.php/customwallpaper/index/create/

will be rewrited to

http://domain.com/index.php/fotomural-personalizado.html

Insert below data in *core_url_rewrite* table for url rewrite

```
Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
    ->setStoreId(1)   
    ->setIdPath('customwallpaper')
    ->setRequestPath('fotomural-personalizado.html')
    ->setTargetPath('customwallpaper/index/create') // Put the actual Controller path
    ->setIsSystem(1)
    ->save();
```

-OR-

Run below sql query

```
INSERT INTO `core_url_rewrite` 
(`url_rewrite_id`, `store_id`, `id_path`, `request_path`, `target_path`, `is_system`, `options`, `description`, `category_id`, `product_id`) 
VALUES ('7', '1', 'customwallpaper', 'fotomural-personalizado.html', 'customwallpaper/index/create', '1', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```